# How do I check what modules where imported when running a function in Jest

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I have a React Native project where I want to limit the number of imports performed on app startup. I've used monitoring tools to remove unnecessary imports, but I'd like the import list to stay lean as I develop the app. Ideally I'd like to use Jest tests to alert me when I add new module import to app start. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it by using Jest `moduleLoader` config option. The setup is rather complicated since it's undocumented API, I described in a [blog post.](https://overengineered.github.io/blog/testing-imports/)